# Generate controls at runtime

Tags: c#

How to generate controls at runtime and set there properties like height, width, Content..

and also their events, like Clicked event

Comment: **1)** You haven't even told us what framework you're using.  **2)** You have not shown that you've put any effort into solving this problem yourself.

Comment: You can edit your post and add some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate controls in C# at runtime

```
// generate button at runtime
Button btn = new Button();

// setting properties
btn.Height = 40;
btn.Width = 100;

// applying events
btn.Clicked += btn_clicked:
```

Answer (score -2):

here I can add the one TextBox on the run time program. when our form will be loaded than Textbox along with add. This TextBox name is "normal" and also tab are working when we are four time press the tab. One more important work is when we are enter in the Text just showing star value.Like that password so on.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.Name = "normal";
        tx.Height = 300;
        tx.Width = 300;
        tx.TabIndex = 4;
        tx.PasswordChar = '*';


    }
```

Comment: Already mentioned above the same Clear answers....

Comment: @faizan i know same but add some more function. The above have no any clear this is created by form load time or button event generated. by the way thanks advice.